# dyamically change onclick functionality for a href jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have a javascript function (to Save the form values) already defined globally in a common js file and now I need to override that with some other functionality based on some condition. Is there any way I can attach a javascript function to the a href onclick dynamically? I tried this way but it is not working. Can anyone please help me?

Parent html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Save();" id="SaveLink"/>
```

Common.js:

```
function Save()
{
    //do something
}
```

My child html calls ValidateForm function (available in Common.js) to validate the form 
and if  it is not valid then stop calling the global Save() function.

```
function ValidateForm()
{
    var responseValid = false; //false for now
    if (!responseValid)
    {
        $("#SaveLink").on("click", function (e) {
            alert("This response is not valid");
            return false;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $("#SaveLink").on("click", "Save();"); //call the global Save function
    }
}
```

**Updated Code:**

```
function ValidateForm()
{
    var responseValid = false; //false for now
    if (!responseValid)
    {
        //$("#SaveLink").prop("onclick", null);
        $("#SaveLink")[0].onclick = null;
        $("#SaveLink").on("click", function (e) {
            alert("This response is not valid");
            return false;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        //call the global Save function
        //$("#SaveLink").prop("onclick", null);
        $("#SaveLink")[0].onclick = null;
        $("#SaveLink").on("click", function (e) {
            Save();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass function handler, not String:

```
 $("#SaveLink").on("click", Save);
```

**EDIT:**

To prevent `onclick` in page you should remove it on DOM ready event. For example:

```
$( function() {
    $( '#SaveLink' )[ 0 ].onclick = null;
});
```

Comment: Have you removed `onclick` from HTML? If yes and you have replaced your code to mine everything should work properly for you.

Comment: I cannot remove onclick from Html page as it is used by lot of other pages and thats why I am trying to override in the common js for child htmls which require additional validation.

Comment: The same issue happens (i.e.) the alert is getting called before Save functionality in success scenario.

Comment: no-no I was meaning that you should set `onlcik` on page load, not inside `ValidateForm` function. It should be up level assuming that this code will be executed when DOM is ready. Try to add my whole code before `function ValidateForm()`

Comment: But if I do that the global Save funtionality will be removed everywhere, right?

Comment: Only from elements w/ `SaveLink` ID. This is only one possible solution as `onclick` fired before jQuery handlers is executed.

Comment: Thanks! I need to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `onclick` event

```
function ValidateForm() {
    var responseValid = false; //false for now
    if (!responseValid) {

        //Remove onclick attribute
        $("#SaveLink").removeAttr('onclick');
        //OR
        $("#SaveLink").prop("onclick", null);

        $("#SaveLink").on("click", function (e) {
            alert("This response is not valid");
            return false;
        });
    } else {
        //call the global Save function
        $("#SaveLink").on('click', Save);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But for some reason in the success scenario it first alerts "This response is not valid" and then calls Save function. It seems to be weird.

Comment: Try `$("#SaveLink").prop("onclick", null);` to remove onclick event

Comment: I tried prop as well but still alert is getting called and then the Save function is getting called in the success scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#"  id="SaveLink" onclick="$.Save(this.id);"/>

 JQuery Code:
 $.Save=function(id)
 {
  //by using id you can apply your conditions 
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I cannot change the global function as lot of other html pages are using the same and I can only override that.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ValidateForm()
{
    var isSave= true; 
    //do your form validation
    if(validation fail)  //if validation fail set isSave is false
       isSave=false;
    return isSave;
}

function save()
{
   if(ValidateForm()) //it will only execute validation is not fail
   {
    // do your code
   }
}
```

OnClick just call save function only

Comment: Sorry I cannot modify the global function